# R: Splitting dataframe columnwise

Tags: r, split, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe with the this structure

```
x = data.frame(let = letters, LET = LETTERS, num1 = 1:26, num2 = 21:46, num3 = 71:96, num4 = 68:93 )
```

I want to split it into list of 3 columns dataframes.The first two columns *let* and *LET* remains common, the third column varies. The first dataframe would be *(let, LET, num1)* and the second one would be *(let, LET, num2)* and so on so forth.

My current strategy is to convert the dataframe into long format and split it based on the *num* using plyr and dplyr packages. Is there an easier way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` like so for your example

```
lapply(1:4, function(D) x[ ,c("let", "LET", paste0("num", D))])
```

If you don't know the column names of the `num*` columns you could use

```
nonLetNames <- names(x)[!(names(x) %in% c("let", "LET"))]
lapply(nonLetNames, function(nom) x[ ,c("let", "LET", nom)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `Map` based approach

```
Map(function(x,y,z) setNames(cbind(x,y), c(names(x), z)), 
            list(x[1:2]), x[-(1:2)], names(x)[-(1:2)])
```